# Mongodb export to SQL tool

Tags: sql-server, export, mongodb

Starting with monbodb.

Administrators are asking a "classical" db for reporting stuff.

Does it exist a tool to export documents to a relational db?

Like having a flattening option or the automatic creation of tables for nested structure.

Comment: This question makes me sad; it reads like they don't want to use MongoDB because they don't know it.  As an Admin, I can say that I'd rather work on MongoDB than MySQL (or similar) any day...

Answer (score 0):

your best bet with the tools is mongoexport using the --csv flag